# How can I check the file I am uploading is in CSV format or Excel? in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, streamlit

```
 uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Choose a file")
    if uploaded_file is not None:
        data = pd.read_csv(uploaded_file)
        #Get overview of data
        st.write(data.head())  
    else:
        data = pd.read_excel(uploaded_file)
        #Get overview of data
        st.write(data.head())
```

It gives me error if I upload excel file, and I understand why. I have to check the uploaded file's extension before reading it in csv or excel format. HOW to check the uploaded file's extension?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood You correctly, there is a simple option.

```
file_split = uploaded_file.split('.')
file_extension = '' if len(file_split) != 2 else file_split[1]
```

Comment: Hint: `uploaded_file` is a `BytesIO` object (subclass), not a `str`. You can access the filename via `uploaded_file.name`.  Suggestion: I would modify your code into something like `ext = uploaded_file.name.split(".")[-1] if "." in uploaded_file.name else None`.

Comment: If you could forward me any link on BytesIO it would be great. @Timus

Answer (score 0):

```
uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Choose a file")
    #converting dic to str 
    conv1 = str(uploaded_file)

#Read file type csv and excel only
    #splitting 
    split1 = conv1.split(sep=':', maxsplit=1)
    store1 = split1[0]
    store2 = store1.split(sep="'", maxsplit=-1)
    store2 = store2[1].split(sep='.', maxsplit=1)
    if store2[1]=="csv":
        st.write("ok")
        df = pd.read_csv(uploaded_file)
        st.write(df.head())
    elif store2[1]=="xlsx": 
        st.write("NotOk")
        df = pd.read_excel(uploaded_file)
        st.write(df.head())
    else:
        st.write("Error: upload the file in csv or excel format")
```

My concepts on ByteIO is not clear. I tried this way with lots of splitting.Its works but this is not efficient way though.

Comment: Have you tried working with `uploaded_file.name`? Imho `ext = uploaded_file.name.split(".")[-1]` should give you the extension.

Comment: it gives the following error `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'name' `

Comment: Okay, could you try it with `ext = uploaded_file["name"].split(".")[-1]`.